# Certificate for programmer?

Tags: certificate

For the networking major, my friend told me they would need to get CCNA Routing and Switching certificate for the education.

But for the software major, is there any certificate that needed to get just to be certified as a programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want certification for web programing you can start with this [Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-480.aspx)

If you need to learn not just for web you can start with this [Programming in C#](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-483.aspx) . These certification are very good because you can be a Microsoft Certification professional with one of them, but there is other vendors that give you certification for programing languages like Java, C++, Python depend of what you think is good for you.